# Trouble with TransitiveClosure function in Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to model graph connectivity with Z3. Specifically I am partitioning a graph and need the subgraphs to remain connected. However `TransitiveClosure` doesn't work as I expect. I model edges with F

Here's a MWE:

```
s = Solver()
N = DeclareSort('N')
a,b,c = Consts('a b c', N)
F = Function(N,N,BoolSort())
s.add(F(A,B) == True)
s.add(F(B,A) == True)

s.add(F(B,C) == False)
s.add(F(C,B) == False)
s.add(F(A,C) == False)
s.add(F(C,A) == False)

s.add(A != B, B != C, C != A)

FX = TransitiveClosure(F)
s.add(FX(A,C))
```

This is apparently SAT, which doesn't make much sense to me. If I change `s.add(FX(A,C))` to `s.add(Not(FX(A,C)))`.

Why is this? C should not be a member of FX. Am I somehow setting `FX(A,C) == True)` by adding it to the model? Why doesn't that conflict with the definition of FX.

The output/connection lines of the model are hard to understand so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure if `TransitiveClosure` is supposed to work on arbitrary/infinitary domains like `IntSort()`. I suspect it might only work when the underlying sort is a new sort declaration. The documentation is not clear on this, however, so you might want to ask at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to get a more definitive answer. If you do so, please post an update!

Comment: Alright that makes sense. I switched it to an uninterpreted sort with one constant per vertex. If I do the same thing with this new sort I still get SAT when I shouldn't. If I set all other edge functions to false why would I get sat asserting that the transitive closure of two disconnected exists? I'll update the code above when I get home.

Answer (score -1):

I am working with tclosures as well and found this helpful: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure)

Maybe there is an answer to your 2nd question as well.